# Враги проходят сквозь объекты и сливаются друг с другом unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

При преследовании игрока враги могут как-бы слиться друг с другом(становясь с виду как-бы одним врагом), а также если зайти за стену они продут через нее.

Код:

```
    private void FollowPlayer()
    {
        var dir = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
        rb.velocity = dir * speed;
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position) <= seeDistance && Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position) > attackDistance)
        {
            speed = speed2;
            EnemyFlip();
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position) <= attackDistance)
        {
            speed = 0;
        }
        if (Hp == 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }
```

Это не весь код, но публиковать весь сразу тоже не вариант.

Код с движением через rigidbody2d:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 movement;
    private int speed = 5;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        target = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Target();
        Vector3 direction = target.position - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        direction.Normalize();
        movement = direction;
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MoveChar(movement);
    }
    private void MoveChar(Vector2 direction)
    {
        rb.MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + (direction * speed * Time.deltaTime));

    }

    private void Target()
    {
        if (target == null)
        {
            Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Звучит страшно)))) Описанное вами - это желаемое поведение или же наоборот косяк? :D

Comment: Это косяк, но почему-то там где я искал как сделать таких врагов, такой фигни не было :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был найден совершенно случайно, если у кого-то будет такая же проблема, то просто отключите freeze position и включайте в случае крайней необходимости :)